# {ctor} is not a member of <BaseClass>

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I Have a baseclass, called GLObject, with the following header:

```
class GLObject{
    public:
        GLObject(float width = 0.0, float height = 0.0, float depth = 0.0, 
                 float xPos= 0.0, float yPos = 0.0, float zPos =0.0, 
                 float xRot =0.0, float yRot = 0.0, float zRot = 0.0);
    ... //Other methods etc
};
```

And a CPP:

```
GLObject::GLObject(float width, float height, float depth, 
                    float xPos, float yPos, float zPos, 
                    float xRot, float yRot, float zRot){
    this->xPos = xPos;
    this->yPos = yPos;
    this->zPos = zPos;
    this->xRot = xRot;
    this->yRot = yRot;
    this->zRot = zRot;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->depth = depth;
}
```

Next up I have a derived class:
Header:

```
class GLOColPiramid : public GLObject
{
public:
    GLOColPiramid(float width, float height, float depth, float xPos = 0.0, float yPos = 0.0, float zPos = 0.0, float xRot = 0.0, float yRot = 0.0, float zRot = 0.0);
    ...
};
```

cpp file

```
GLOColPiramid::GLOColPiramid(float width, float height, float depth, float xPos, float yPos, float zPos, float xRot, float yRot, float zRot) : GLObject::GLObject(width, height, depth, xPos,yPos,zPos,xRot,yRot,zRot)
{

}
```

This gives me an error:

> glocolpiramid.cpp:4: error: C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of
>   'GLObject'

why?

I am using Qt 4.8.4 with the MSVC2010 32 bit compiler

Comment: Try to remove `GLObject::` from `GLObject::GLObject` in the declaration (cpp).

Comment: Wow, you are right. Could it be true that this is not an illegal statement on Linux/g++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `GLObject::` from `GLObject::GLObject` in the declaration.

In `.cpp` file which contains implementation of `GLOColPiramid`:

```
GLOColPiramid::GLOColPiramid( .... ) : GLObject::GLObject( .... )
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's legal in C++ but test it, maybe MSVC2010 has problem with it.

Comment: Maybe should also metion that you mean the cpp file of GLOColPiramid not the one of GLObject.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't explicitly reference the base class constructor using the `BaseClassName::BaseClassName(...)` syntax when calling it from the derived class constructor - that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Instead, just use the base class name and pass the parameters:

```
GLOColPiramid::GLOColPiramid(float width, float height, float depth, float xPos, float yPos, float zPos, float xRot, float yRot, float zRot) : GLObject(width, height, depth, xPos,yPos,zPos,xRot,yRot,zRot)
{

}
```